# How to display different element in HTML Source editor in tinymce?

Tags: javascript, tinymce

I want to add my own control to tinymce editor (for example `<editable />`).
This control must display form like:

```
<div class="editable">
<label>Test<input type="text" /></label>
<label>Test2<input type="text" /></label>
</div>
```

No problems for now. I can do that.
But I need to make it readonly (no problems with it as well - using noneditable plugin)

My problem is:
if user press "Edit HTML Source", I must display `<editable />` element only (without labels and textboxes).

I don't know if it is possible, but looking to the `Embeded Media` element -
it shows image in editor, but replace it with iframe in HTML Source.

Comment: Resolved without any answer

Comment: please post your answer here too, so that other users can profit from your efforts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My result is little bit simpler.
I just removing `<cms:control />` tag's content from HTML Source editor.

On tinymce init make following:

```
 ed.onPreInit.add(function () {
        ed.parser.addNodeFilter('cms:control', function (nodes) {
            var i = nodes.length;

            while (i--)
                objectToHtml(nodes[i], ed.schema);
        });

        ed.serializer.addNodeFilter('cms:control', function (nodes, name, args) {
            var i = nodes.length, 
                node;

            while (i--) {
                node = nodes[i];
                htmlToObject(node, args);
            }
        });
    });

    function objectToHtml(node, schema) {
        node.empty();

        var html = '<label>Test<input type="text" /></label>' +
                   '<label>Test2<input type="text" /></label>';                     

        var parser = new tinymce.html.DomParser({validate: true}, schema);
        var rootNode = parser.parse(html);

        node.append(rootNode);           
    }

    function htmlToObject(node, args) {
        node.empty();           
    }
```